How. to read or retry the process for uncommited message in kafka
lets say i am getting 1 to 15 messages from kafka. I am processing it and commiting it, if the message does satisfy the condition I am uncommiting the particular message.
Now, My question is how to retry or read the message and try process until it commit.
And, If the message i retries for 5 times how to capture those information.
I commited only the succes case. i am tried in different auto.offset.reset config but still now i cannot able to reprocess or retry it. If you had any idea please share it..

Show us the code. What is "uncommitting"? In Kafka, you commit offsets, meaning you ack for messages up to a given offset, you don't ack for each message individually.

Kafka offset commits are effectively a "cumulative ack": if you commit after processing message 4 in a given TopicPartition, you are acknowledging messages 0 through 3 as well, so your consumer will not see those messages again.
In general, especially if processing multiple messages from a TopicPartition, if you want to guarantee that messages will be processed at least once, you need to not commit until you know that all preceding messages have successfully processed.  Note that this means messages which were successfully processed may be reprocessed: it is thus useful to make the processing idempotent when possible (e.g. by persisting that a given message was successfully processed in some database and checking if that message is referenced in that database before doing the full processing).
An alternative strategy is to produce the message that failed to retry/dead-letter topic for a different consumer to attempt reprocessing.

It's good, but you may see the same message multiple times. Why should not store the particular offset and retry it later using seek()?

And it is possible only in the case of Kafka Consumer. It won't work for Kafka Streams. Streams need to follow the low level processor Api approach.
